# Flex Webservice

Tags: web-services, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm using Flash Builder 4.5 and flex 4.5 language.
I'm using a webservice to retrieve data in json calling a .php.

```
<webservice:Webservice id="webservice" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)" showBusyCursor="true"/>
<s:CallResponder id="testResult" result="onTestResult(event)"/>

...

private function onTestResult(e:ResultEvent):void{
    Alert.show(ObjectUtil.toString(testResult.lastResult));
}
```

In the "Test Operation" window of Flash Builder I made my call and the return is a json Object made by arrays.

If I call the same webservice from the code instead, it returns a (object)#0 so an empty Object. No errors thown, just an empty Object.

Anyone has some tips?

Comment: Is it accessing the webservice?Are there any server log updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ns prefix of your `Webservice` class susggests you're using a custom implementation, rather than the framework `WebService` class.  However, you don't provide any specifics, so I'm gonna take a swing in the dark:

If your custom service is based off the `HTTPService` class, make sure you're setting the `resultFormat='text'`.  The default is `XML`, which will be causing you problems.

If you're using the Framework `WebService` class, well - you can't, as it's designed for SOAP webservices, not JSON.  (From the Docs for `mx.rpc.soap.WebService`:)

> The WebService class provides access to SOAP-based web services on
>   remote  servers.

If it's some other implementation, please provide more details.

Comment: The problem was in the resultFormat. I've set a generic Object(), but flex seems doesn't like the conversion myResult -> Object, so I've made a custom myObjectType() with fields exactly named as the returned JSON serialized array and the data is inserted correctly.